# Google maps mark con puntos desde la base de datos

Tags: android, sql-server, google-maps

quiero obtener los puntos, nombre y descripción ademas de 2 valores para agregar al snippet, pero al ejecutar el código que tengo la app no se cae, pero queda en negro, a continuacion dejo mi codigo

```
public class Marcadores {

    String ip, db, un, passwords;
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement stmt;
    ResultSet rs;

    public void MarcadoreBdd(GoogleMap map) {
        ip = "mssql4.gear.host";
        db = "ciclomapp1";
        un = "ciclomapp1";
        passwords = "Mk36-9DX-580";

        String query = "select ru.nombre , ru.descripcion , avg(va.valoracion) ,re.tipo, ru.ubicacion  \n" +
                "from (Rutas ru inner join valorar va on ru.nombre=va.nombre_ruta) \n" +
                "inner join reporte re on re.nombre_ruta =Ru.nombre\n" +
                "group by ru.nombre,ru.descripcion , va.valoracion ,re.tipo, ru.ubicacion; ";
        try {
            con = connectionclass(un, passwords, db, ip);
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Ruta b = null;
                b.nombre = rs.getString("nombre");
                b.descripcion= rs.getString("descripcion");
                b.ubicacion= rs.getString("ubicacion");
                b.valoracion=rs.getString("valoracion").toString();
                b.reporte=rs.getString("reporte");
                String [] point=b.ubicacion.split(",");
                double latitude = Double.parseDouble(point[0]);
                double longitude = Double.parseDouble(point[1]);
                LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                String valorar=String.valueOf(b.getValoracion());

                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).snippet(b.descripcion+ System.getProperty ("line.separator")+"Valoracion de la ruta"
                        +valorar+System.getProperty ("line.separator")+"Estado de la ruta: Posible"+b.reporte));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public Connection connectionclass (String user, String password, String database, String server){
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            Connection connection = null;
            String ConnectionURL = null;
            try {
                Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
                ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server + "/" + database + ";user=" + user + ";password=" + password + ";";
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                Log.e("error here 1 : ", se.getMessage());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("error here 2 : ", e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("error here 3 : ", e.getMessage());
            }
            return connection;
        }
}
```

Comment: ¿La base de datos la tienes en local o en la nube?

Comment: esta hosteada, osea en la nube

Answer (score 2):

Si tu base de datos esta en la nube, así no es la forma en que debes de hacerlo.

Para poder interactuar con la base de datos necesitas crear un [API](http://asiermarques.com/2013/conceptos-sobre-apis-rest/) en donde exista un servicio web que te regrese la información que necesitas.

Lo que hace el api es:

1. Tu le pides información
2. El API recibe esa petición y consulta a la base de datos
3. La base de datos le regresa la información
4. La API recibe la información de la BD y te la regresa (a la app móvil)

Cuando tengas lista tu API y tus servicios web te sugiero que uses [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) es una librería que te ahorra muchisimo trabajo...

***Cuando ya tengas todo listo***:
Un ejemplo de como puedes recibir la info de la base de datos es mediante un `Json` (el cual `Retrofit` ya haría el parse y solo tendrías que utilizar la info recibida)

e.g.

```
[{
    "nombre": "punto 1",
    "descripcion": "bla bla",
    "lat": "10.012",
    "lng": "-10202"
}, {
    "nombre": "punto 2",
    "descripcion": "bla bla",
    "lat": "10.012",
    "lng": "-10202"
}, {
    "nombre": "punto 3",
    "descripcion": "bla bla",
    "lat": "10.012",
    "lng": "-10202"
}, {
    "nombre": "punto 4",
    "descripcion": "bla bla",
    "lat": "10.012",
    "lng": "-10202"
}]
```

Lo de arriba es un JsonArray

Ahora, lo que tendrías que hacer después es decirle a Retrofit que lo que vas a recibir es un `JsonArray` por lo cual debes de almacenarlo en una lista.

```
{
   "nombre": "punto 4",
   "descripcion": "bla bla",
   "lat": "10.012",
   "lng": "-10202"
}
```

Esto es un objeto del `JsonArray` por lo tanto tu lista será de objetos

Algo así como `ArrayList<MiObjeto> miListaDeObjetos`

```
public class MiObjeto {
String nombre;
String descripcion;
double lat;
double lng;

...

setters 
getters
}
```

Ya que tengas esto solamente quedaría pintar en el mapa mediante un foreach los markers

```
for (MiObjeto obj : miListaDeObjetos){
      MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
       .position(new LatLng(obj.getLat(), obj.getLng()))
       .title(obj.getNombre());

     googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
}
```

Espero te ayude. Usar un API me parece una mejor práctica. 
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

[Robert](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/31222/20449) tiene razón, debes usar buenas practicas de programación.
Cuando creas una app movil, es recomendable ejecutar las consultas de la base de datos en un servidor, y no en la misma aplicación. Porque tenderas a duplicar código y tu código sera poco legible, así se recomienda principalmente dividir tu sistema.

Puedes crear una API(API REST O API RESTFUL) en el lenguaje que quieras php, java,etc.

Cuando realices consultas desde la app android a la base de datos puedes usar Retrofit como dice [Robert](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/31222/20449) o puedes usar Volley que es mas simple http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/02/android-volley-peticiones-http/

Ademas, para realizar tus pruebas a la api, puedes probar las consultas a tu servidor usando POSTMAN o otro 'api client rest' https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop

Por ultimo revisa si tu servidor tiene acceso publico, es decir si puedes conectarte a el. Si tienes acceso a la bd o a carpetas del servidor.

PD: cuando publiques no muestres ip, nombre de bd, ni menos passwords :)